# Mogenerator Assertion failed: (momcTool && "momc not found"), function -[MOGeneratorApp setModel:]

Tags: core-data, mogenerator

I can't get Mogenerator 1.27 to generate the NSManagedObject classes as I'm getting this error:

> Assertion failed: (momcTool && "momc not found"), function -[MOGeneratorApp setModel:], file /tmp/mogenerator-LDeD/mogenerator-1.27/mogenerator.m, line 643.
>   Abort trap: 6

I'm using this command:

`mogenerator -m myApp/myModel.xcdatamodeld/myModel.xcdatamodel -O myApp/Model --template-var arc=true`

The exact same command works on my old computer, but not on my new one with the same version of Mogenerator. Why would it not work on my new computer?

Comment: Obvious but, is Xcode installed, and the command line tools? The problem is it can't find the model compiler.

Comment: @TomHarrington I had Xcode 6 Beta 3 and Command Line Tools for OS X 10.9 July 2014 installed. Your comment spurred me to install the Xcode 5 and it worked.  Thank you! If you'd like, leave an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to tell Xcode which command line tools to use, in Preferences/Locations. I had accumulated several from Xcode 4, 5 and 6 and this selection had become blank somehow.

[image]