# How can i solve CoreData mogenerator not found issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I got the error as shown below. I don't know what did i miss? How can i solve this issue as shown in image below:

> /Users/nischalhada/Documents/XcodePro/mnepalnews-revisited-2.0/CoreData
>   mogenerator not found Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

[image]

**Screen shots of run script**

[image]

I am unable to solve my problem after study of following
[Mogenerator not found by Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248302/mogenerator-not-found-by-xcode),

[Mogenerator Assertion failed: (momcTool && "momc not found"), function -[MOGeneratorApp setModel:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816463/mogenerator-assertion-failed-momctool-momc-not-found-function-mogener)

[Mogenerator Assertion failed: (momcTool && "momc not found"), function -[MOGeneratorApp setModel:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816463/mogenerator-assertion-failed-momctool-momc-not-found-function-mogener)

[how to fix the issue "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1" in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006464/how-to-fix-the-issue-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-iphone)

I have done both of the following but it doesn't work out

> First Methods

[image]

> Second methods

[image]

Comment: That is the problem of the POD shell script?

Comment: how can we solve that

Comment: have you use any external library?

Comment: so why are you use POD?

Answer (score 0):

`mogenerator` is not in your Xcode PATH.

You can modify your run script to specify the full path for `mogenerator`:

```
/usr/local/bin/mogenerator --model ...
```

Comment: where can i do that can u please help me out

Comment: You didn't show the run script, so I can't specifically say, but a likely place to check is *Pods-resources.sh*.